# HTML Code for multiple images to different text pop up box

Tags: javascript, html, image, web, popup

I am trying to create a "Meet the Team" page for my website. I want am currently working on a code where the staff member's picture is displayed and when you click it, their bio comes up. I got the code to work for one staff member, but I can't get the text to change between pictures. This is what I have. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

CSS code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.row > .column {
  padding: 2px 15px;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}

.column {
  float: left;
  width: 33.3%;
}


#Img {
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

#Img:hover {opacity: 0.7;}


/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.9); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 80%;
}

/* Add Animation */
.modal-content, #caption {  
  -webkit-animation-name: zoom;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.6s;
  animation-name: zoom;
  animation-duration: 0.6s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes zoom {
  from {-webkit-transform:scale(0)} 
  to {-webkit-transform:scale(1)}
}

@keyframes zoom {
  from {transform:scale(0)} 
  to {transform:scale(1)}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15px;
  right: 35px;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: bold;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #bbb;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px){
  .modal-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.title {
  color: navy;font-family: "Source Sans Pro", arial, sans-serif;line-height: 1.5;
}

h2 {
color: navy;font-family: "Source Sans Pro", arial, sans-serif;line-height: 1.5;
}

p {
  color: rgb(94, 94, 94);font-family: "Source Sans Pro", arial, sans-serif;line-height: 1.5;
}
</style>
```

HTML Code

```
</head>
<body>

<img class="faculty"   src="image.pgn" alt="image" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;height:250px">
    <p class="title">Name of Staff Member</p>
</div>

<div class="column">
    <img class="faculty" src="img.pgn" alt="img" style="width:100%;max-width:300px;height:250px">
    <p class="title">Staff Member Name</p>
</div>


<div id="modal01" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <span class="close">&times;</span>
            <THIS IS WHERE I WANT INFORMATION TO GO>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="modal02" class="modal">
  <span class="close">&times;</span>
  <div class="modal-content">
    THIS IS WHERE STAFF INFO WOULD GO
  </div>
</div>
```

JS Code

```
<script>

var modal = document.getElementById('modal01');

var images = document.getElementsByClassName('faculty');

for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
  var img = images[i];
  
  img.onclick = function(evt) {
    console.log(evt);
    modal.style.display = "block";
    modalImg.src = this.src;
    captionText.innerHTML = this.alt;
  }
}

var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the unnecessary code.  We only need to see the code **segment** that pertains to your question.  So, just the HTML and JS that is specific to the pictures/text and the event that should change the text.

Comment: Okay hopefully I fixed it so it is easier to read now.